# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un Join en una relación OneToMany usando CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo dos entidades Autor y Libro con una relación OneToMany

Quiero usar CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery para primero hacer un Join, que me devuelva todos los libros con su nombre de autor.
Y después añadirle filtros como que la categoría sea "Aventura" y el autor "Julio Verne" por ejemplo.

Entidad Autor, donde declaro la relación OneToMany mapeada al campo "autor" de la clase Libro

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Autor")
public class Autor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="idAutor")
    private Long idAutor;

    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="nacionalidad")
    private String nacionalidad;

    // El autor tendrá una lista de libros escritos por él
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Libro> libros = new ArrayList<Libro>();
```

Entidad "Libro" con la relación @ManyToOne con Autor

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Libro")
public class Libro implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="idLibro")
    private Long idLibro;

    @Column(name="titulo")
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name="categoria")
    private String categoria;

    @Column(name="fecha")
    private int fecha;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAutor")
    private Autor autor;
```

He seguido algunos ejemplos y en 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939173/criteria-query-for-unidirectional-one-to-many-relationship?rq=1
he encontrado un ejemplo que me podría servir pero no entiendo el uso de guión bajo
en ese solución...

```
Root<Supplier> supplierRoot = query.from(Supplier.class);
ListJoin<Supplier, POS> posList = supplierRoot.joinList(Supplier_.posList);
```

Como podría hacer esas consultas y si alguien puede indicarme alguna páguina donde explique el uso de guión bajo, 
porque he tratado de recrear ese ejemplo pero marca error.

Hasta ahora sólo he conseguido consultas de una tabla usando un criterio de esta forma:

```
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();       
        CriteriaQuery<Libro> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Libro.class);      
        Root<Libro> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Libro.class);     
        Predicate condiciones = criteriaBuilder.and(
                criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("categoria"), "Aventura"));      
        criteriaQuery.where(condiciones);       
        Iterable <Libro> libros = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo no lo haria en el criteria si no directamente en el entity quedaria algo asi:

**Libro**

```
...
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idAutor", nullable=false)
        private Autor autor;
...
```

**Autor**

```
...
                @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor")
                private List<Libro> libros;
...
```

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Con esto solo tienes que hacer el find y con los correspondientes getters obtendras los valores

Answer (score 0):

Para quien le pueda servir de ayuda creo que he encontrado una solución en esta web 
http://www.thejavageek.com/tag/joins/

````
```
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();       
CriteriaQuery<Libro> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Libro.class);
Root<Autor> itemAutor = criteriaQuery.from(Autor.class);
Join<Autor, Libro> libros = itemAutor.join("libros");
Predicate condiciones = criteriaBuilder.and(
        criteriaBuilder.equal(itemAutor.get("nombre"), "Julio Verne"), 
        criteriaBuilder.equal(libros.get("categoria"), "CIFI")
        );
criteriaQuery.select(libros).where(condiciones);
Iterable <Libro> misLibros = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```
````